# Pod lib lint fail - Auto-Linking supplied ... file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I'm making a pod in Swift 3 and when I try to lint my project, I have some errors with the build.

I'm using Xcode 8.2 (beta) and macOS Sierra.

Here's the error I got:

```
      ..................

      ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    ** BUILD FAILED **

     The following build commands failed:
     Ld /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bfgilsvmbnmybfcdfnlsszcgntbe/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/LocalPusher.build/Objects-normal/i386/LocalPusher normal i386
     (1 failure)
    -> LocalPusher (1.0.0)

     [!] LocalPusher did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
     You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.

    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  warning: target specifies SWIFT_VERSION = '3.0', but it is overridden by TOOLCHAINS = 'swift'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftFoundation.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftFoundation.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftDispatch.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftDispatch.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCore.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCore.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftUIKit.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftUIKit.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftDarwin.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftDarwin.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreImage.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    [!] LocalPusher did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
    You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have the rep to add this as a comment.

The error you received mentions using --verbose for more information.
You should re-run your command adding `--verbose` (and share that output if that doesn't clearly point you to the problem). That will provide more detail into the error that's occurring.